# Linq- Get main that has property of list<string> where list<string> contain string

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a List that has a property of List. How can I get the any List when the string items in its property List contain a string?

Here is my code but it return nothing.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Plist> a = new List<Plist>()
        {
            new Plist()
            {
                Name="a",
                StringList=new List<string>()
                {
                    "a1","b1","c1"
                }
            },
            new Plist()
            {
                Name="b",
                StringList=new List<string>()
                {
                    "a2","b2","c2"
                }
            },new Plist()
            {
                Name="c",
                StringList=new List<string>()
                {
                    "a3","b3","c3"
                }
            },new Plist()
            {
                Name="d",
                StringList=new List<string>()
                {
                    "a4","b4","c4"
                }
            }
        };
        var list = a.Where(n=>n.StringList.All(s=>s.Contains("a"))).Take(3);

        foreach(Plist items in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{items.Name}");
            foreach(string item in items.StringList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"    {item}");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

public class Plist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> StringList { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to Linq so hope all of you help me out of this.

Comment: Your use of `All` means that every element in that collection must be true for the given condition. Your condition is that every string in `StringList` contains the letter "a". Looking through your `Plist`s, none of the `StringList`s satisfy that condition, so `Where` will return an empty collection. And `Take`ing 3 elements from an empty collection will result in nothing. I can't really suggest where you go from here without knowing what your overall goal is.

Comment: Your `linq` line sounds like copy paste

Comment: `All` will return the PList that all of its stringlist contains 'a', 
You may read the definition according to msdn 
`All Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.` 
Whereas `Any Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.`
one more thing, it is not good practice to use '.Take()' without ordering.

Comment: Thank you to all of you for your recommended. I get my answer and new knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your LINQ states that every (`All()`) item in inner list has to contain `"a"`. What you want to check whether `Any()` of the items contains `"a"`.

To do so you should use `Any()` instead of `All()`:

```
var list = a.Where(n => n.StringList.Any(s => s.Contains("a")));
```